# Search Biztalk tracking database by promoted property

Tags: biztalk

Is there a way to search in tracking DB in Biztalk Administration Console using the custom promoted message property?

Comment: Did my answer below help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.

First you have to select Schema Name from the drop down, and then select that schema of the message, and then the promoted property on the next line, see [How to Search for Tracked Message Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/how-to-search-for-tracked-message-events)

[image: Searching on Promoted Properties]